# AWS Glue - Export Spark dataframe to CSV, include all values in quotes except NULL

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

In AWS Glue, I have a Spark `dataframe` that was loaded from a SQL Server table, so it does have actual NULL values (not the string "null") in the data.
I want to write this `dataframe` out into a CSV file in a way that all values are quoted with double quotes, except those NULL values.

I tried using the options `quoteAll=True`, `nullValue=''`, `emptyValue=''` in the `dataframe.write` operation:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").mode('overwrite').options(header='true', path=output_path, escape='\\', quoteAll=True, nullValue='', emptyValue='').save()
```

However, this also quotes NULL values - here is an example where col2 is NULL:

```
col1, col2, col3
"value1","","value3"
```

Instead, I need this:

```
col1, col2, col3
"value1",,"value3"
```

What is the easiest and/or cleanest way to achieve that (I realize cleanest vs easiest might be 2 different solutions...)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the parameter `nullValue` and set to `nullValue=None`.

Comment: Nope; that also results in a pair of empty quotes...
But thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I ended up doing the quoting as part of the select() logic on the source side.
My source is a SQL Server DB table, so it was easy to check for null; then take all non-NULL values, put quotes around them, and escape existing quotes within the values.
Then on the destination side in the CSVWriter parameters, completely disable all quoting / escaping.

Probably not the nicest solution, because it feels like I am fixing a destination issue on the source side; but it does work...

I was also looking into writing a custom CSVWriter by somehow inheriting from the original one, but had a hard time finding the right place to do the overwrite...
Any pointers to that end would be appreciated!